# How to add Banner/Slider using JQuery in MVC4 Razor View Page

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Recently I need to add a banner /slider using J-Query in Master layout.cshtml page in MVC4 project , this is razor view page, any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should choose jQuery slider plugin (there are plenty of them, just find one that fits your needs). Each of them has instructions how to setup it.

As for Master layout I've used several approaches:

`@Html.Partial("_Slider")` - if you don't need to load images dynamically
- `@Html.Action("Slider", "Home")` - you can get data from DB and render partial view from controller's action

Hope this helps.